# What is modeling language in Blockchain? Where it is use?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

Where we need to use modeling language in Blockchain?

**Permissions.acl** file use which language? 
**.cto** file use which language? is it modeling language?

I know that **logic.js** file use the JavaScript language.

Please clear me about Modeling Language.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Am I ask anything wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From The **https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language**

**Hyperledger Composer** includes an **object-oriented modeling language** that is used to define the domain model for a business network definition.
A Hyperledger Composer **CTO** model file is composed of:

- A single namespace. All resource declarations within the file are
  implicitly in this namespace.
- A set of resource definitions, encompassing assets, transactions,
  participants, and events.
- Optional import declarations that import resources from other
  namespaces.

And From the **https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language.html**
**Hyperledger Composer** includes an **access control language (ACL)** that provides declarative access control over the elements of the domain model. By defining ACL rules you can determine which users/roles are permitted to create, read, update or delete elements in a business network's domain model.

Answer (score 1):

From Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modeling_language

**Modeling Language:** A modeling language is any artificial language that can be used to express information or knowledge or systems in a structure that is defined by a consistent set of rules. The rules are used for interpretation of the meaning of components in the structure.

From Hyperledger Github: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-website/jekylldocs/reference/cto_language.md

The Hyperledger Composer modeling language is an object-oriented language which defines the business network model containing assets, participants, and transactions.

You can also see this tutorial. This tutorial will help to develop a project using Hyperledger Composer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2S5cEcmx7Q

Comment: Thank you so much.